# Are questions about issue tracker recommendations on topic?

Tags: discussion, on-topic-definition

Is this question on-topic here on Programmers SE:

[Issues Tracker for both developers and end users](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/157531/issues-tracker-for-both-developers-and-end-users)

The [FAQ](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/faq) doesn't explicitly disallow such questions nor does it seem to explicitly allow them.

In general, shopping recommendations are considered off-topic for the Stack Exchange engines but some allowances are made for them if the question asks how to make a good shopping decision rather than simply crowdsourcing the community and letting random people on the Internet make a decision for you.

From [Q&A is Hard, Let's Go Shopping](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/):

> “Give a man a fish and you feed him for a day. Teach a man to fish and you feed him for a lifetime.” Every question and answer ultimately should be about teaching and learning — yes, even the shopping ones.

I noticed the question has been here for a week, is upvoted, and has no close votes on it. So, what's the verdict. Should this be closed? If it's on-topic, why?

Comment: I voted to close it.

Answer (score 3):

It appears that the question is asked specifically enough so that it can be answered definitively; i.e. there are enough requirements specified in the question so that it won't generate an unbounded list of people's favorite Issue Trackers.

Shopping questions of the "What is your favorite thing" are definitely off-topic, but if a user can ask a question in such a way that they are asking *how* to make their shopping decision rather than asking *what* thing they should choose, then it's generally allowed.

Answer (score 1):

If you classify a bug tracker as a programming tool its off topic, if the question wants recommendations of which bug tracker is best its not constructive. Keeping track of bugs is art of software development so it should be possible to make an on topic question about bug trackers, but it would be difficult to make it constructive.

Comment: So, did the op succeed in this case?

Comment: @jmort253 I would say it's on the borderline, its not awful, but it is getting some poor answers